# Changing certain values in multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame at once

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
  apple banana cherry
0     0      3   good
1     1      4    bad
2     2      5   good
```

This works as expected:

```
In [2]: df['apple'][df.cherry == 'bad'] = np.nan
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  apple banana cherry
0     0      3   good
1   NaN      4    bad
2     2      5   good
```

But this doesn't:

```
In [2]: df[['apple', 'banana']][df.cherry == 'bad'] = np.nan
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  apple banana cherry
0     0      3   good
1     1      4    bad
2     2      5   good
```

Why?  How can I achieve the conversion of both the 'apple' and 'banana' values without having to write out two lines, as in

```
In [2]: df['apple'][df.cherry == 'bad'] = np.nan
In [3]: df['banana'][df.cherry == 'bad'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should use loc and do this **without chaining**:

```
In [11]: df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['apple', 'banana']] = np.nan

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   apple  banana cherry
0      0       3   good
1    NaN     NaN    bad
2      2       5   good
```

*See the docs on [returning a view vs a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), if you chain the assignment is made to the copy (and thrown away) but if you do it in one loc then pandas cleverly realises you want to assign to the original.*

Comment: Is it easy to extend this to the case where np.nan is instead another data frame with the shape of ```df[['apple', 'banana']][df.cherry == 'bad']``` ?

Comment: @dermen it should "just work", though you may have issues aligning (on the index).... you may have to assign `other_df.values`. Perhaps worth asking as another question if that fails?

Comment: I was having troubles doing this,  which lead me to this posting.. and as it turns out, assigning ```other_df.values``` is the way to go.

Comment: Is there a way to do this, but assign NaN to apple and 123 to banana ?

Answer (score 5):

It's because `df[['apple', 'banana']][df.cherry == 'bad'] = np.nan` assigning to the copy of DataFrame. Try this:

```
df.ix[df.cherry == 'bad', ['apple', 'banana']] = np.nan
```

Comment: Don't use api `ix` again, use `loc` or `iloc` instead, see this [What is meant by ".ix is deprecated" in Python Pandas?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-ix-is-deprecated-in-Python-Pandas)

Answer (score 1):

While this question is broad, the answers seem very specific and not very versatile. This is just to clarify...

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Test1' :[1,2,3,4,5], 'Test2': [3,4,5,6,7], 'Test3': [5,6,7,8,9]})

   Test1 Test2 Test3
0  1     3     5
1  2     4     6
2  3     5     7
3  4     6     8
4  5     7     9

# When the index or row you want to edit is known
df.loc[3, ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'] = [10, 12, 14]

# When you don't know the index but can find it by looking in a column for a specific value

df.loc[df[df['Test1'] == 4].index[0], ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']] = [10, 12, 14]

   Test1 Test2 Test3
0  1     3     5
1  2     4     6
2  3     5     7
3  10    12    14
4  5     7     9
```

Both methods allow you to change the values of multiple columns in one line of code.