# Multi-column replacement in Pandas based on row selection

Tags: python, pandas

There are a plethora of questions on SO about how to select rows in a `DataFrame` and replace values in a column in those rows, but one use case is missing. To use the example `DataFrame` [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867734/changing-certain-values-in-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-at-once),

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
  apple banana cherry
0     0      3   good
1     1      4    bad
2     2      5   good
```

And this works if one wants to change a single column based on another:

```
df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', 'apple'] = df.banana * 2
```

Or this sets the values in two columns:

```
df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['apple', 'banana'] = np.nan
```

But this doesn't work:

```
df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['apple', 'banana'] = [df.banana, df.apple]
```

, because apparently the right side is 3x2, while the left side is 1x2, hence the error message

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

So I understand what the problem is, but what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can try:

```
df['a'] = df.apple * 3
df['b'] = df.banana * 2
print df
   apple  banana cherry  a   b
0      0       3   good  0   6
1      1       4    bad  3   8
2      2       5   good  6  10

df[['a', 'b']] = df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['apple', 'banana']] 
print df
   apple  banana cherry    a    b
0      0       3   good  NaN  NaN
1      1       4    bad  1.0  4.0
2      2       5   good  NaN  NaN
```

Or use conditions with [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df['a'] = df.apple * 3
df['b'] = df.banana * 2

df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['apple', 'banana']] = 
df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['a', 'b']].values
print df
   apple  banana cherry  a   b
0      0       3   good  0   6
1      3       8    bad  3   8
2      2       5   good  6  10
```

Another options with original columns:

```
print df[['apple','banana']].shift() * 2
   apple  banana
0    NaN     NaN
1   12.0     6.0
2    2.0     8.0

df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['apple', 'banana']] = df[['apple','banana']].shift() * 2
print df
   apple  banana cherry
0    6.0     3.0   good
1   12.0     6.0    bad
2    2.0     5.0   good
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution is the one I was looking for. So basically in my case, it would be `df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['apple', 'banana']] = df.loc[df.cherry == 'bad', ['banana', 'apple']].values`. Interestingly enough, it doesn't work without the `values`, even though I inverted the column names. Anyway, just one more question: is there a way without adding new columns to `df` if I want something special (e.g. `df.banana * 2`)? Maybe with `apply`?

Comment: Thanks, that looks good -- so basically I could do sth like `df.loc[...] = pd.concat([df.banana * 3, df.apple * 2], axis=1).values`. Apparently, values was the magic bullet I was looking for, thanks!