# Add multiple calculated columns to a pandas dataframe at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, httprequest, text-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
 ID1    ID2  Len1   Date1   Type1   Len2    Date2   Type2   Len_Diff    Date_Diff   Score
 123    456         1-Apr    M              6-Apr    L          
 234    567         20-Apr   S              19-Apr   S          
 345    678         10-Apr   M              1-Jan    M
```

I want to fill in the columns that are Len1, Len2, Len_Diff and Date_Diff by calculating them from the dataset. Each ID corresponds to a text file and whose text can be retrieved using a `get_text` function and the length of that text can be calculated

As of now, I have code that can do this individually for each column:

```
def len_text(key):
   text = get_text(key)
   return len(text)

df['Len1'] = df['ID1'].map(len_text)
df['Len2'] = df['ID2'].map(len_text)
df['Len_Diff'] = (abs(df['Len1'] - df['Len2']))
df['Date_Diff'] = (abs(df['Date1'] - df['Date2']))
df['Same_Type'] = np.where(df['Type1']==df['Type2'],1,0)
```

How can I add all these columns to the dataframe in one step. I want them in one step because I want to wrap the code in a try/except block to overcome value errors from failure to decode the text.

```
try: 
    <code to add all five columns at once>
except ValueError: 
    print "Failed to decode"
```

Adding a try/except block to each line above makes it ugly.
There are other questions like: [Changing certain values in multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867734/changing-certain-values-in-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-at-once), that deal with multiple columns, but they are all talking about one calculation/change affecting multiple columns. What I want is different calculations to add different columns.

**UPDATE:** From the answers given below, I tried two different ways to approach the problem, with *partial* luck so far. Here's what I did: 
**Approach 1:**

```
# Add calculated columns Len1, Len2, Len_Diff, Date_Diff and Same_Type
def len_text(key):
    try:
        text = get_text(key)
        return len(text)
    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.Timeout, ValueError) as e:
        return 0

df.loc[:, ['Len1','Len2','Len_Diff','Date_Diff','Same_Type']] = pd.DataFrame([
        df['ID1'].map(len_text),
        df['ID2'].map(len_text),
        np.abs(df['ID1'].map(len_text) - df['ID2'].map(len_text)),
        np.abs(df['Date1']- df['Date2'])
        np.where(df['Type1']==df['Type2'],1,0)
    ])

print df.info()
```

*Result1*:

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> RangeIndex: 570 entries, 0 to 569
> df columns (total 10 columns):
> ID1                  570 non-null int64
> Date1                570 non-null int64
> Type1                566 non-null object     
> Len1                 0 non-null float64
> ID2                  570 non-null int64
> Date2                570 non-null int64
> Type2                570 non-null object     
> Len2                 0 non-null float64     
> Date_Diff            0 non-null float64   
> Len_Diff             0 non-null float64
> dtypes: float64(4), int64(4), object(2)
> memory usage: 58.0+ KB
> None
> ```

**Approach2:**

```
def len_text(col):
    try:
        return col.map(get_text).str.len()
    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.Timeout, ValueError) as e:
        return 0

formulas = """
     Len1 = @len_text(ID1)
     Len2 = @len_text(ID2)
     Len_Diff = Len1 - Len2
     Len_Diff = Len_Diff.abs()
     Same_Type = (Type1 == Type2) * 1
     """
try:
    df.eval(formulas, inplace=True, engine='python')
except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.Timeout, ValueError) as e:
    print e

print df.info()
```

*Result2:*

> ```
> "__pd_eval_local_len_text" is not a supported function
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> RangeIndex: 570 entries, 0 to 569
> df columns (total 7 columns):
> ID1             570 non-null int64
> Date1           570 non-null int64
> Type1           566 non-null object
> ID2             570 non-null int64
> Date2           570 non-null int64
> Type2           570 non-null object
> Len1            570 non-null int64
> dtypes: int64(5), object(2)
> memory usage: 31.2+ KB
> None
> /Users/.../anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/computation/eval.py:289:
> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   target[parsed_expr.assigner] = ret
> ```

Comment: Why not put all five lines in the same try/except?

Comment: @Jerome, I tried. Only the first column is being populated when I do that.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [DataFrame.eval()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) method:

```
In [254]: x
Out[254]:
   ID1  ID2   Date1 Type1   Date2 Type2
0  123  456   1-Apr     M   6-Apr     L
1  234  567  20-Apr     S  19-Apr     S
2  345  678  10-Apr     M   1-Jan     M

In [255]: formulas = """
     ...: Len1 = @len_text(ID1)
     ...: Len2 = @len_text(ID2)
     ...: Len_Diff = Len1 - Len2
     ...: Len_Diff = Len_Diff.abs()
     ...: Same_Type = (Type1 == Type2) * 1
     ...: """
     ...:

In [256]: x.eval(formulas, inplace=False, engine='python')
Out[256]:
   ID1  ID2   Date1 Type1   Date2 Type2  Len1  Len2  Len_Diff  Same_Type
0  123  456   1-Apr     M   6-Apr     L     3     3         0          0
1  234  567  20-Apr     S  19-Apr     S     3     3         0          1
2  345  678  10-Apr     M   1-Jan     M     3     3         0          1
```

PS this solution assumes that the `len_text()` function can accept a column (Pandas.Series). For example:

```
def len_text(col):
    return col.map(get_text).str.len()
```

Comment: But `Len1` is not suppose to be the length of `ID1`... the value of `ID1` gets passed to `get_text` which returns a string, and it's the length of *that* string that is of interest.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for your comment. I've fixed it

Comment: @MaxU, This works awesomely. It looks clean too. Except, I still have the same problem. Len_Diff is not getting populated just like with the previous answer.

Comment: @MaxU, Infact, only `Len1` is getting populated. No other column.

Comment: @Minu, make sure that each new column in `formulas` is on the new line - it's important. Beside that what is happening with another new columns - errors, they are empty, something else?

Comment: @MaxU, they are empty. I have updated the question with the code I'm using now.

Comment: @Minu, as i have mentioned, my solution expects that the `len_text()` function can work with vectors - see an example in my answer

Comment: @MaxU, I tried wrapping the function that you provided in a try/except block to see if it works with the code. Same result. See update in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the job

EDIT 2: here is actually really nasty way to make it in *one assignment* evaluating the `Len1` and `Len2` multiple times.

```
df.loc[:, ['Len1', 'Len2', 'Len_Diff', 'Date_Diff', 'Same_Type']] = \ 
    pd.DataFrame([
        df['ID1'].map(len_text),
        df['ID2'].map(len_text),
        np.abs(df['ID1'].map(len_text) - df['ID2'].map(len_text)),
        np.abs(df['Date1'] - df['Date2']),
        np.where(df['Type1']==df['Type2'],1,0)
    ])
```

However, it is much less readable then original version.

EDIT: Here is a nicer way to do it in 2 lines.

```
df.loc[:, ['Len1', 'Len2']] = \ 
    pd.DataFrame([
        df['ID1'].map(len_text),
        df['ID2'].map(len_text)
    ])

df.loc[:, [ 'Len_Diff', 'Date_Diff', 'Same_Type'] = \
    pd.DataFrame([
        np.abs(df['Len1'] - df['Len2']),
        np.abs(df['Date1'] - df['Date2']),
        np.where(df['Type1']==df['Type2'],1,0)
    ])
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work.... the evaluation of the RHS will occur before the assignment... So `abs(df['Len1'] - df['Len2'])` would be working with the wrong data, for example.

Comment: oh, that's true, in that case, it is impossible to make it in one line.

Comment: Well, maybe not *impossible*, but certainly not cleanly ;)

Comment: I like your EDIT2 solution. One small thing -  i think we should use `np.abs()` instead of `abs()`

Comment: @matusko, The Edit2 is working like a charm. However, there's a problem: `Len_Diff` is not getting populated. Not sure why.

Comment: @matusko, On second thought, the code isn't working when wrapping it in the try/except block.

Comment: could you expand on that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you could do this:

```
>>> df
      a  b     c
0  None  1  None
1  None  2  None
2  None  3  None
3  None  4  None
>>> def f(val):
...     return random.randint(1,10)
...
>>> df.loc[:,['a','c']] = df[['a','c']].applymap(f)
>>> df
    a  b   c
0   3  1   7
1  10  2  10
2   6  3   4
3   4  4   8
```

So, in your case:

```
df.loc[:,['Len1', 'Len2']] = df[['ID1','ID2']].applymap(len_text)
```

However, to be frank, you are likely better off with the ugly version, because then you'll know which column is giving you an error.

Comment: I tried this too, but I get an error `KeyError: ('ID1', 'ID2')`

Comment: @Minu that's odd. Are you sure the column names are exactly those? E.g. no errant whitespace?

Comment: This would not generalize well in case you want to apply various functions (which is exactly the case of this question). Right?

Comment: @matusko ah, good point, yes, but I believe the OP just wants to avoid wrapping every line in a `try-except`, but these are the columns that would actually throw that error!

Comment: The column names are correct. No white spaces. 
@matusko I agree about this not generalizing, but I am just curious why it wouldn't work.