# How to add multiple calculated columns to dataframe at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe as below

```
Slno Name_x  Age_x   Sex_x Name_y  Age_y   Sex_y
0    1      A     27    Male      A     32    Male
1    2      B     28  Female      B     28  Female
2    3      C      8  Female      C      1  Female
3    4      D     28    Male      D     72    Male
4    5      E     25  Female      E     64  Female
```

I need to create calculated column , difference between age, check gender match and to achieve this in one go I am using

```
DF3.loc[:,["Gendermatch","Agematch"]]=  pd.DataFrame([np.where(DF3["Name_x"]==DF3["Name_y"],True,False),np.where(DF3["Age_x"]-DF3["Age_y"]==0,True,False)])
```

and the resultant dataframe looks like as below

```
Slno Name_x  Age_x   Sex_x Name_y  Age_y   Sex_y  Gendermatch  Agematch
0    1      A     27    Male      A     32    Male          NaN       NaN
1    2      B     28  Female      B     28  Female          NaN       NaN
2    3      C      8  Female      C      1  Female          NaN       NaN
3    4      D     28    Male      D     72    Male          NaN       NaN
4    5      E     25  Female      E     64  Female          NaN       NaN
```

Resultant columns shows not a number , what wrong am I doing here?

Comment: please add your `dataframe.head(10).to_dict()`, or better, define it using `dictionary`

Comment: Can you help me on this with details please, I am new to Python

Comment: just use `DF3.head(10).to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

```
DF3[["Gendermatch","Agematch"]]=  np.where(DF3["Name_x"]==DF3["Name_y"],True,False),np.where(DF3["Age_x"]-DF3["Age_y"]==0,True,False)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
DF3[["Gendermatch","Agematch"]] = pd.DataFrame([np.where(DF3["Name_x"]==DF3["Name_y"],True,False),np.where(DF3["Age_x"]-DF3["Age_y"]==0,True,False)]).T
```

Comment: I would like to achieve the output  as mentioned  in below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667934/add-multiple-calculated-columns-to-a-pandas-dataframe-at-once

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` is useless, Series comparison already returns boolean Series

```py
DF3["Gendermatch"] = DF3["Name_x"]==DF3["Name_y"]
DF3["Agematch"] = DF3["Age_x"]==DF3["Age_y"]
# or in one line
DF3["Gendermatch"], DF3["Agematch"] = (DF3["Name_x"]==DF3["Name_y"]), (DF3["Age_x"]==DF3["Age_y"])
```

```
print(DF3)

   Slno Name_x  Age_x   Sex_x Name_y  Age_y   Sex_y  Gendermatch  Agematch
0     1      A     27    Male      A     32    Male         True     False
1     2      B     28  Female      B     28  Female         True      True
2     3      C      8  Female      C      1  Female         True     False
3     4      D     28    Male      D     72    Male         True     False
4     5      E     25  Female      E     64  Female         True     False
```

Comment: I would like to achieve results as shown in below link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667934/add-multiple-calculated-columns-to-a-pandas-dataframe-at-once

Comment: @sriharshab.s. Don't understand